# chinese chars - PHP encoding

Tags: php, encoding, cjk

I am trying to extract chinese words off a website.

I am using simple cURL code:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;
```

Expected result for one of words is

```
网络频率
```

However I get this:

```
ÍøÂçÆµÂÊ
```

Also if I url encode word result is different.

I am having problems with encoding lately.
Chinese chars are UTF8 or what?
Could anyone help me chars would show "normal" with echo and if I url encode them result will be same as if I copy them off website.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chinese is usually UTF-8, yes. The problem you're having is probably not that the data isn't received correctly (cURL knows what it's doing), but that you're not sending them correctly to the browser.

Try this on top of your page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This will tell the browser that you are sending UTF-8 information.

**Update**: if this doesn't work, it could be that PHP itself isn't handling them properly. Try playing with `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode` a bit in your `echo`. If thàt doesn't work, then cURL isn't decoding the stream properly, which means you'll have to look for the `Content-Type` header in the response and decode the stream accordingly.

Comment: Hey Tom I tried that too before but it was even worse.I just got strange question marks :/

Comment: Updated my answer with two additional ideas.

Comment: Hey thanks @Tom Content-type part was very helpful.
I figured out they use gb2312 encoding.Echo works good now.
PHP default charter encoding is utf8 right?
so now I am searching a way to convert it from gb2312 to utf8 right?

Comment: You should be able to use `utf8_encode($response, 'gb2312');` for that.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, it seems it accepts 1 parameter only.
And php.net says utf8_encode is used to convert from ISO-8859 to UTF-8

Comment: In that case: `utf8_encode(utf8_decode($response, 'gb2312'));` or simply `iconv('gb2312', 'utf-8', $response);` (second one would be preferred)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

1) create a new document and make sure the document is UTF-8 compatible

2) Use metal tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

3) I wouldn't recommend forcing header into using utf-8, but simply use ini_set

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

if you are calling curl function from a different page, make sure that page is able to carry UTF-8 characters and pass it onto UTF-8 compatible page.

Comment: ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8'); is a good way to fix from server side.