# How to parse html and access chinese strings?

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, proxy

This is my `proxy.php` file:

```
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$url = 'http://' . str_replace('http://', '', $url);
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

And this is my `reader.js` file:

```
    var site = 'http://wanteddomain.com/index.aspx?lang=34&team1=0&team2=0&next_turn=1'

    var url = 'http://localhost/mydomain.pl/admin/proxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(site)

    $.ajax({
        url      : url,
        type     : 'GET',
        contentType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
        dataType : 'html'
    }).done(function(res) {

        //when I access special dom element, I have for example æ³°æå°å¡ instead of 广告
    });
```

What to do to have chinese characters?

Comment: check the files' encoding. Everything should be saved as UTF-8.

Comment: Where to check this?

Comment: If you have a code editor, open up all the files (php/js/html, etc.) and see what the encodings are set / saved as.

Comment: I checked and saved every file with encoding utf-8. Still the same.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496271/how-to-properly-display-chinese-characters-in-php - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143452/php-utf8-not-displaying-chinese-characters-properly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548932/chinese-chars-php-encoding if any of those help and you didn't use any of what's been suggested. There isn't much else I can do for you here, sorry.